# How to get the content of specific grandchild from xml file through python

Tags: python, xml, grandchild

Hi I am very new to python programming. I have an xml file of structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<LidcReadMessage xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nih.gov http://troll.rad.med.umich.edu/lidc/LidcReadMessage.xsd" 
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                  xmlns="http://www.nih.gov" uid="1.3.6.1.4.1.14519.5.2.1.6279.6001.1307390687803.0">
    -<ResponseHeader>
        <Version>1.8.1</Version>
        <MessageId>-421198203</MessageId>
        <DateRequest>2007-11-01</DateRequest>
        <TimeRequest>12:30:44</TimeRequest>
        <RequestingSite>removed</RequestingSite>
        <ServicingSite>removed</ServicingSite>
        <TaskDescription>Second unblinded read</TaskDescription>
        <CtImageFile>removed</CtImageFile>
        <SeriesInstanceUid>1.3.6.1.4.1.14519.5.2.1.6279.6001.179049373636438705059720603192</SeriesInstanceUid>
        <DateService>2008-08-18</DateService>
        <TimeService>02:05:51</TimeService>
        <ResponseDescription>1 - Reading complete</ResponseDescription>
        <StudyInstanceUID>1.3.6.1.4.1.14519.5.2.1.6279.6001.298806137288633453246975630178</StudyInstanceUID>
    </ResponseHeader>
    -<readingSession>
        <annotationVersion>3.12</annotationVersion>
        <servicingRadiologistID>540461523</servicingRadiologistID>
        -<unblindedReadNodule>
            <noduleID>Nodule 001</noduleID>
            -<characteristics>
                <subtlety>5</subtlety>
                <internalStructure>1</internalStructure>
                <calcification>6</calcification>
                <sphericity>3</sphericity>
                <margin>3</margin>
                <lobulation>3</lobulation>
                <spiculation>4</spiculation>
                <texture>5</texture>
                <malignancy>5</malignancy>
            </characteristics>
            -<roi>
                <imageZposition>-125.000000 </imageZposition>
                <imageSOP_UID>1.3.6.1.4.1.14519.5.2.1.6279.6001.110383487652933113465768208719</imageSOP_UID>
                ......
```

There are four  which contains multiple . Each  contains an . I need to extract the information in from all of these   headers.

Right now I am doing this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('069.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
#lst = []
for readingsession in root.iter('readingSession'):
    for roi in readingsession.findall('roi'):
        id = roi.findtext('imageSOP_UID')
    print(id)
```

but it ouputs like this:

Process finished with exit code 0.
If anyone can help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See my EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem as been wit the namespace. I tried with and without it, but it didn't work with this code.

```
    ds = pydicom.dcmread("000071.dcm")
    uid = ds.SOPInstanceUID
    tree = ET.parse("069.xml")
    root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    print(child.tag)
    if child.tag == '{http://www.nih.gov}readingSession':
        read = child.find('{http://www.nih.gov}unblindedReadNodule')
        if read != None:
            nodule_id = read.find('{http://www.nih.gov}noduleID').text
            xml_uid = read.find('{http://www.nih.gov}roi').find('{http://www.nih.gov}imageSOP_UID').text
            if xml_uid == uid:
                print(xml_uid, "=", uid)
                roi= read.find('{http://www.nih.gov}roi')
                print(roi)
```

This work completely fine to get a uid from dicom image of LIDC/IDRI dataset and then extract the same uid from xml file for it region of interest.